# PHP cURL pass Cookie to website

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, curl, fopen

I am trying to fetch this image using cURL:

```
http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=-Claire%21&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=std&size=m&img_format=gif
```

If you visit this Site in the Browser, you will see an image, but if I use Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=-Claire%21&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=std&size=m&img_format=gif");
$fp = fopen($img, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

The Image File just contains this HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1) 
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '176.198.73.37', 10);
location.href = getHostUri();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried to include a cookies.txt which is in the same directory as the script that is executed. The cookies.txt has 777 rights and looks like this:

```
YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666=176.198.73.37;
```

I thought that would do the trick, as it seems to me that I do need a cookie to get the image, but it doesn't work. Does anyone understand the procedure and can tell me how to download that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to perform two requests: 1st for initial download and 2nd for passing cookie.

Secondly this cookie is set by Javascript. cURL can't handle such cookies. So you have to handle this cookie manually: parse its value from html and pass it to next cURL request. You can do it by setting option CURLOPT_COOKIE.

Comment: Shameless plug: In the case of extra HTTP cookies presence besides Javascript cookie you may use [Cookie Jar Writer] (https://github.com/hindmost/cookiejarwriter) in conjunction with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option. This PHP class allows to add custom cookie variables to a cookie jar file within sequence of cURL requests.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at that! :)